# Regex search for records for a complete match starting from the 10th character to the first

Tags: regex

I have a problem with form a regex condition.I have a text

```
1234567890,text1,text11, some text...
1204500006,text2,text22, some text...
1216432200,text3,text33, some text...
1234812000,text4,text44, some text...
```

I need to form a regex that will find entries in which the first number (the first 10 characters) has a combination of 00 starting from the end.

input:

```
1234567890,text1,text11, some text...
1204500006,text2,text22, some text...
1216432200,text3,text33, some text...
1234812000,text4,text44, some text...
```

output:

```
1216432200,text3,text33, some text...
```

I wrote a regex that looks for the first 10 characters, but I can't add a search to it starting from the end of those 10 characters ^([0-9]{10})

Please help solve this issue.

Comment: play with https://regex101.com/

Comment: Based upon your samples and your expected results, [`^\d{7}[1-9]00,.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/Ksybpk/1) regex should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

For at least a single occurrence of `00` without any surrounding `0`'s you could make use of lookarounds if that is supported:

```
^(?=\d{10}\b)\d*(?<!0)00(?!0).*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=\d{10}\b)` Positive lookhead, assert 10 digits followed by a word boundary (or change the `\b` to `,` if that should be there)
- `\d*` Match optional digits
- `(?<!0)00(?!0)` Match `00` not surrounded by 0
- `.*` Match the rest of the line

[Regx demo](https://regex101.com/r/XM97XR/1)

If only the 8th digit can not be a zero, you can match 7 digits, and for the 8th digit you can use a character class `[1-9]` to omit matching a zero:

```
^\d{7}[1-9]00\b.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YrCkoc/1)

Answer (score 1):

Solution is simple in sometimes. Please you try this:

`^\d{8}00[^\n]+`

Unfortunately, first index of string can configurate with `^` character.

Answer (score 0):

Please use https://regex101.com/
I did it and found this solution.

```
^\d{8}00.+$
```

Comment: it's cool,but this doesn't work if you only want to find strings that have a number at the end of 0. If you can change the condition for the full match of characters starting from the end of the number, this would solve this problem